# EF Core - unknown relationship define foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to link the default `IdentityUser` with a custom generic class called `Permission<TUser>` where is this case `TUser = IdentityUser`. The class is defined as follows:

```
public class Permission<TUser> {
    public TUser User { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Restrictions { get; set; }
}
```

The `Identifier` is the type of permission and NOT unique. That means the model only has a composite pk using the foreign key of the user and the permission identifier. That's what I defined:

```
builder.Entity<Permission<IdentityUser>>()
       .HasKey(p => new {p.User, p.Identifier});
```

But to set the foreign key of the permission I have to define a relationship and I don't know which one this is.

Comment: EF Core cannot map a generic class to a table.  You can use a generic base and then create a concrete subclass (without generics) that can be mapped by EF Core.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. But that does not solve the problem to define a foreign key without knowing the kind of relationship

Comment: Have added an answer for configuring a one-to-many relationship, which is what your above model would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a one-to-many relationship from IdentityUser to Permission, so:

```
builder.Entity<Permission>()
    .HasOne<IdentityUser>(p => p.User)
    .WithMany();
```

EF Core will assign a foreign key by convention.  If your navigation property is 'User' then the FK will be 'UserId'.

You can override the Foreign key by continuing the above configuration with:

```
.HasForeignKey("IdentityUserId");
```